# ORDER BY in SQL is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query :

```
SELECT 
       conversations_messages.conversation_id, 
       MAX(conversations_messages.message_date) AS 'conversation_last_reply', 
       MAX(conversations_messages.message_date) > conversations_users.last_view AS 'conversation_unread'
FROM 
        conversations_messages
        LEFT JOIN conversations ON conversations_messages.message_id=conversations.id
        INNER JOIN conversations_users ON conversations_messages.conversation_id=conversations_users.conversation_id
WHERE 
        conversations_users.user_id = $user_id AND 
        conversations_users.deleted=0
GROUP BY 
        conversations_messages.message_id
ORDER BY 
        'conversation_last_reply' DESC
```

And the query in running well as I want, but only the last line, of the ORDER BY is not working, its not sorting as I requested.

**And the only thing that is not working - is the last line - ORDER BY...**
I tried to change it to ASC and to DESC again but its not responding...
* by the way - the field that I'm trying to sort by - is an integer.

Someone knows what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: no need the quotes. order by a column name, not by a string literal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
ORDER BY conversation_last_reply
```

instead of

```
ORDER BY 'conversation_last_reply'
```

Your current version sorts by a constant string, so it does not sort at all.

Comment: dang barely beat me! gj! +1 from me :)

Answer (score 1):

you have quotes around your order by

```
ORDER BY 
    'conversation_last_reply' DESC
----^-----------------------^------ = bad
```

you should change it to

```
ORDER BY 
    conversation_last_reply DESC
```

or use backticks

```
ORDER BY 
    `conversation_last_reply` DESC
```

when you order by a string there is no ordering because the value of the string is always the same for every row :)

Comment: @DavidAlexandrovich you dont have to accept mine but please dont forget to mark an answer as accepted! :) it makes others want to continue to answer questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `order by conversations_messages.message_date` ?

Comment: todd that wouldn't work because the OP wants to order by the `MAX(date)` instead of just the date :)

Comment: Yes but I had to sort by a specific mathematic function MAX

Answer (score 0):

Try without adding the quotes  orderby

```
ORDER BY conversation_last_reply
```